# Intellij launch error: Could not find main class com/intellij/idea/Main

Tags: windows, intellij-idea-2016

Intellij launch error in a Windows Environment.

When launching from the "Start Menu" getting a popup window with the following error:

```
Could not find main class com/intellij/idea/Main
```

Seems like a possible classpath issue. Can anyone recommend a quick fix, maybe in one of properties files?

Comment: Post your code. With this info is almost impossible to determine what the problem is.

Comment: This is not a coding issue. I am trying to get Intellij itself to launch in a windows environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For PyCharm, this worked:

- Uninstall PyCharm
- Download and install JDK 8
- Set your system variables
- Reinstall PyCharm

Answer (score 3):

For me its resolved for IntellijIdea version 22, i was getting below error when i changed IntelliJ Default JRE to JRE 17
[image]

Just we need to remove **"idea64.exe.jdk"** for me this location is **"C:\Users{UserName}\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IdeaIC2022.1\idea64.exe.jdk"**.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error with jdk version 17, but when I switched to jdk version 11 the error was resolved.

Also set the system environment variable to your system's jdk location:

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.11
```